# Possibility to follow questions

Tags: feature-request, notifications

Sometimes I find a question that seems interesting and for some reasons I may want to follow it even though no one tag me or comment my answer (if any).

I can have different reasons for that:

1. from strictly personal like being busy at the moment
2. waiting for a clarification by the OP (say when a reproducible example is requested in comments)
3. being curious to see other answers then mine.

So, I was thinking to something like the "favourite question" star but with temporary effect (users can choose among 1h/1day/1week) and enabling notification as I were tagged via `@`

Comment: Would the question's activity RSS feed (link in lower right of page) meet your need? Or are you really wanting an expiration of the favoriteing action?